# My printer doesn't have wifi so can i make a ubuntu the wifi for that printer?

Tags: printing

So I have a Windows PC at my Office and I have a secondary Ubuntu PC that makes servers and other stuff. My printer is connected VIA USB to my Ubuntu so every time I want to print something I have to get up my fat ass and go to the Ubuntu computer to print it and a USB or have the files on my office Cloud.

What I want is to make my Windows PC to be able to send a file to the Ubuntu PC and the Ubuntu PC automatically prints that file, through WIFI or the local network.

If you could help me with this, I could be eternally grateful, for now thanks.

Comment: I don't know details (hence not posting as an answer) but you can go into the printer settings on the Ubuntu computer and share the printer.  The part I'm fuzzy on is how to get the Windows machine to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to "share" the printer over Samba. There are many HOWTO's on the Internet to do this, here is one:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

You have already installed the printer on Ubuntu. You may already have installed Samba; if not, that would be the next step. Then, *share*  the printer.  Make sure that both computers can ping each other, and belong to the same "Workgroup". The printer should now be visible on your Windows computer in the "Network" window, so you can print to it.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I have tested it and it works perfectly.